# Node / Express / EJS: How can I get value from index.ejs and pass it to server.js

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I know how to read values from an HTML-form with app.post() in server.js.

But now the location (longitude and latitude) is generated at client-side and needed on server-side.

So my question is, how do I pass that location-values from index to server.js?

I guess my app.get() has to be modified:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

// get values from index
// ...
console.log("Yeehaa!" + latitude + " " + longitude)

// Render index.ejs 

res.render('index',{locs:nearbyLocations})
```

});

Thx
pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass longitude, latitude as query params:

Serverside code:

```
app.get(
  '/locations/nearby', 
  async (req, res) => {
    const {latitude, longitude} = req.query;

    console.log("Yeehaa!" + latitude + " " + longitude)
    const locations = ... getting locations nearby ...;

    res.render('index', {locations});
  });
```

Client-side as a link:

```
<a href="/locations/nearby?latitude={latitude-here}&longitude={longitude-here}">
  Nearby locations
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to put a <a href...> in a button or so. I want the user to call localhost:3000 (or some other domain) without parameters. Then the coordinates are generated at client side and pusched to server in some way. the server then renders the page depending on coordinates. Is that possible?

Comment: @piccus it's impossible due to security considerations of browser vendors and OS. Think: will You feel comfortable if anyone will know where You are now? You can take latitude and longitude using browser's location API and pass it to some url as parameters or using JavaScript You can save it in cookies and pass it that way (without passing through query attributes). If idea is to get city, You can get it using geoip module which gets requestors IP as argument and returns location info (Google it: npm geoip).